# Create sublists with elements 1 and 2 in alternate ways in Scala

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

Hi all I am new with Scala and I have a doubt:

Creation of sublists with elements 1 and 2 in alternate ways, never having two consecutive numbers repeated.

My function:

```
def functionAlternateElements(list : List[Int]): Option[List[Int]] = {
//What should be the solution?
}
```

Tests:

```
test("AlternateElementsTests") {
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1)) === Some(List(1)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2)) === Some(List(2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3)) === Some(List(1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5)) === Some(List(2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) === Some(List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) === Some(List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)) === Some(List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)) === Some(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)))
assert(ca1.functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)) === Some(List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
```

}

How can I do this?

If you know the code can you give an explanation so I can understand it please?

Comment: I have an explanation: `Seq(1*2+1+1+2,1+1*2+1+1*2,1+1*2+1+1*2).mkString` gives `666`, therefore your quality assurance department has been infiltrated by the illuminati, and `1+2-1-1+2-1-1+2-1-1+2-1-1+2-1-1+2` gives `3`, therefore HalfLife 3 confirmed. Or maybe it's just an unclear question that you should clarify.

Comment: You are not ok , and i am sorry but Half Life 3 Will never exist

Comment: It will not? Ok... But then you certainly have a more logical explanation for the seemingly completely arbitrary sequence "1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,...". Would you mind sharing your explanation? You can't just dump a function signature and a wall of seemingly arbitrary requirements, and then expect that anyone can help you with that, because it's completely unclear what the function is supposed to do. Even copy-pasting the expected output into the function body won't help, because we have only first 17 elements. Any guarantee that 18-th output doesn't "have to" start with a 7 or 15?

Comment: And it's not only about the initial numbers: the lengths of the sequences on the right hand side seem just as weird: 1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,... maybe you could explain this as well.

Comment: The numbers inside the element "list" are not important. In this tests the numbers inside the list are in a sequence way but once again they could be random numbers. What is important here is the number of elements of the list. For example if the list receives 3 elements then the output would be Some(List(1, 2))).

Comment: If the numbers inside the `list` are not important, why do you pass them as arguments in the first place, instead of passing in an integer? Let me summarize: there are now 17 assertions there, on the left hand side are inputs that apparently do not matter, and on the right hand side are outputs without any recognizable pattern in them. You still made no attempt whatsoever to explain what those strange "1,2,1,1,2,..." sequences mean. You've only said that all lists with 3 elements must be mapped to `Some(List(1,2))`, without explaining why. That does not uniquely determine the whole function.

Comment: This is a school exercise. The main focus its to learn to work with lists. I know this function generates a strange sequence, but still a sequence. So yes, it could be a integer instead of a list. So if it was a integer, how could I create this strange sequence? That's my problem mate.

Comment: The problem is that I still don't understand what the "strange sequence" is supposed to be, I see only first 17 values, and I don't recognize any pattern. Are you sure that you quoted the statement of your exercise in the most precise way, and that you also didn't somehow corrupted the test-data while copying it around?

Comment: No, they only say that information and gave me this test cases. If you see the sequence, after the 17th element there would be two lists starting with value 1. And the 20th would start with value 2. And that's all the way up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the assertions seem to be more or less arbitrary, I don't know how to write a program that can produce these strange outputs.

However, I know how to *write a program that can write a program* that can produce these strange outputs. The idea is to *generate code* that satisfies the requirements. We will generate it by supplying an ansatz and then searching for a bunch of magic numbers by brute-force.

---

First, let's build some infrastructure. We need a tiny framework for solving arbitrary problems by brute force. Here is a trait that is useful for very small problems:

```
trait BruteForce[X] {
  def engageBruteForceAttack(constraint: X => Boolean): Option[X]
  def zip[Y](other: BruteForce[Y]): BruteForce[(X, Y)] = 
    new ProductBruteForce[X, Y](this, other)
}
```

We need to handle only the finite case and the case of cartesian product:

```
class FiniteBruteForce[X](possibilities: List[X])
extends BruteForce[X] {
  def engageBruteForceAttack(constraint: X => Boolean) = possibilities.find(constraint)
}

object FiniteBruteForce {
  def apply[X](xs: X*) = new FiniteBruteForce[X](xs.toList)
}

class ProductBruteForce[A, B](a: BruteForce[A], b: BruteForce[B])
extends BruteForce[(A, B)] {
  def engageBruteForceAttack(constraint: ((A, B)) => Boolean) = {
    var solution: Option[(A, B)] = None
    a.engageBruteForceAttack { x => 
      b.engageBruteForceAttack { y => 
        if (constraint((x, y))) {
          solution = Some((x, y))
          true
        } else {
          false
        }
      }.map(_ => true).getOrElse(false)
    }
    solution
  }
}
```

Now we can extract the inputs and outputs from your test cases:

```
val mysteriousTestCases = List(
  (List(1), List(1)),
  (List(1,2), List(2)),
  (List(1,2,3), List(1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4), List(1, 2, 1)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5), List(2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6), List(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16), List(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)),
  (List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17), List(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
)
```

Now let's write a program that will write us the function that computes the strange 1,2,1,1,2,... sequence:

```
val (illuminatiPivot, (illuminatiOffset, illuminatiShift)) = 
  FiniteBruteForce(-1, -2, 0, 1, 2).zip(
    FiniteBruteForce(-1, -2, 1, 2, 3).zip(
      FiniteBruteForce(0, 1, 2)
    )
  ).engageBruteForceAttack{ case (p, (o, s)) => 
    mysteriousTestCases.forall { case (input, output) =>
      val (start :: tail) = output
      val n = input.size
      val illuminatiNumber = 
        if (n < p) (n + o) 
        else List(1, 1, 2)((n + s) % 3)

      start == illuminatiNumber
    }
  }.get

println(s"""|// The function that generates the start number
            |// of the strange sequences
            |def illuminatiNumber(n: Int): Int = {
            |  if (n < $illuminatiPivot) (n + $illuminatiOffset)
            |  else List(1, 1, 2)((n + $illuminatiShift) % 3)
            |}
            |""".stripMargin)
```

Now do the same for the lengths of the outputs. The ansatz is this time: it should be some affine-linear function that grows with factor 2/3 and is rounded in a weird way:

```
val (hl3ConfirmedConst, hl3ConfirmedOffset) = 
  FiniteBruteForce(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2).zip(
    FiniteBruteForce(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
  ).engageBruteForceAttack{ case (c, o) => 
    mysteriousTestCases.forall { case (input, output) =>
      val n = input.size
      val halfLife3Confirmed = c + (n * 2 + o) / 3
      output.size == halfLife3Confirmed
    }
  }.get

println(s"""|def halfLife3Confirmed(i: Int): Int = {
            |  $hl3ConfirmedConst + (i * 2 + $hl3ConfirmedOffset) / 3
            |}
            |""".stripMargin)
```

Finally, I didn't bother to think hard enough how to map `1` to sequence `1,2,1,2,...` and `2` to `2,1,2,1,...`, so I brute-forced this too:

```
val (tabulationOffset, tabulationShift) = 
  FiniteBruteForce(-1, 0, 1, 2).zip(FiniteBruteForce(0, 1)).engageBruteForceAttack{
    case (x, y) =>

    (0 to 2).map(i => x + (y + 1 + i) % 2).toList == List(1, 2, 1) &&
    (0 to 2).map(i => x + (y + 2 + i) % 2).toList == List(2, 1, 2)
  }.get
```

Now we can write out the initially seeked `functionAlternateElements`-method:

```
println(s"""|def functionAlternateElements(list : List[Int]): Option[List[Int]] = {
            |  val n = list.size // throw away everything but the size
            |  val resultStart = illuminatiNumber(n)
            |  val resultSize = halfLife3Confirmed(n)
            |  Some(List.tabulate(resultSize){ i => $tabulationOffset + ($tabulationShift + resultStart + i) % 2 })
            |}
            |""".stripMargin)
```

Let's also write out the assertions again:

```
for ((i, o) <- mysteriousTestCases) {
  val input = i.mkString("List(", ",", ")")
  val output = o.mkString("List(", ",", ")")
  println(s"""assert(functionAlternateElements($input) == Some($output))""")
}
```

And also let's append a line that tells us that everything went well in the end:

```
println("""println("All assertions are true")""")
```

When run, the above contraption produces the following code:

```
// The function that generates the start number
// of the strange sequences
def illuminatiNumber(n: Int): Int = {
  if (n < -1) (n + -1)
  else List(1, 1, 2)((n + 0) % 3)
}

def halfLife3Confirmed(i: Int): Int = {
  0 + (i * 2 + 1) / 3
}

def functionAlternateElements(list : List[Int]): Option[List[Int]] = {
  val n = list.size // throw away everything but the size
  val resultStart = illuminatiNumber(n)
  val resultSize = halfLife3Confirmed(n)
  Some(List.tabulate(resultSize){ i => 1 + (1 + resultStart + i) % 2 })
}

assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1)) == Some(List(1)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2)) == Some(List(2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3)) == Some(List(1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4)) == Some(List(1,2,1)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5)) == Some(List(2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) == Some(List(2,1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1,2,1)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) == Some(List(2,1,2,1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)) == Some(List(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)) == Some(List(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)))
assert(functionAlternateElements(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)) == Some(List(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)))
println("All assertions are true")
```

When we execute the generated code, we get only:

```
All assertions are true
```

and no AssertionErrors. Thus, we've managed to implement the strange function successfully.

Tip of the day: you know that your specification is bad when the only way to satisfy the tests is by brute-forcing a bunch of magic numbers.

Comment: This is a gigantic implementation. You are right this is really a random exercise... thanks for the time spent mate. You really understand a lot of this.

Comment: @AndréAzevedo I hope it's somewhat inspiring. I've learnt quite a bit by writing programs that solve my homework, instead of solving it manually. I'd advice you too to solve the exercises in this way as often as feasible (I mean, by writing programs, I don't mean by brute-forcing, hopefully that's not necessary). It's really fun :)